# Join 3 table and prevent Duplicate Details

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hello I got this 3 table and I want to make a single joined table with no duplicate details.

```
User Table

userLRN userLevel
```

```
user_information Table
userInfoID  userLRN userFirstname userLastname userMiddlename userSex userContactNumber userYearGraduated
```

```
workinfo Table
workinfoID userLRN workOccupation
```

Design:

> User Table is to one user_information
>   user_information is to many
>   workinfo

I tried this SQL Query:

```
SELECT userLRN, userFirstname, userLastname, userMiddlename, userSex,
userContactNumber, userYearGraduated, workOccupation 
From user_information 
INNER JOIN users on user_information.userLRN = users.userLRN 
INNER JOIN workinfo on workinfo.userLRN = user_information.userLRN 
WHERE users.userLevel = users
```

and I got multiple names and id.
I want to combine the same id and name with different work.
Please Help me with this.

I want this output:
[Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVClZ.png)

Comment: first decide what server you are running on for tags. Next consider throwing `distinct` in as the 2nd word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0b740/1) and comments below, try:

```
SELECT user_information.userLRN, userFirstname, userLastname, 
group_concat(workOccupation) as workStuff 
From user_information 
INNER JOIN users on user_information.userLRN = users.userLRN 
INNER JOIN workinfo on workinfo.userLRN = user_information.userLRN 
WHERE users.userLevel = 'user' 
group by user_information.userLRN, userFirstname, userLastname;


+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
| userLRN | userFirstname | userLastname | workStuff         |
+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
|       1 | Al            | Go           | Work1,Work2,Work5 |
|       2 | Megan         | Fox          | Work4             |
+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

mysql manual page on [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

A Percona article entitled [The power of MySQL’s GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/)

Comment: It looks like the same @Drew

Comment: Need to see the data you have. Sqlfiddle.com

Comment: great. before I look, say how you want the output to look. I am off somewhere helping someone.

Comment: I want that the there is only one name but inline with different work on same row. Like Al Go will have one row and inline Work1, work2 and work5 @Drew

Comment: you want a comma separated list for one column

Comment: I would like to combine All Work occupation on same person @Drew

Comment: Thanks A LOT. It is what I want @Drew